# Twitter-style user account down arrow

Tags: css, menubar, drop-down-menu

I would like to replicate the down arrow that appears next to a username on several sites such as Twitter.

[image: Twitter]

I believe there are two ways of doing this: create a down arrow image and set it as some sort of background image, or use CSS to create the arrow. I believe Google uses the CSS approach for their top bar.

Which option is preferred and how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter is using the `&darr;` html entity (appending it with css `content` property). In combination with an image sprite, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/HAZGr/

[image]

My advice would be to use an image, it keeps it simple and that way you know it will look the same on all browsers.

Comment: Good pick up with the `&darr;` I inspected Twitter with firebug, but it doesn't pick up :after or :before tags.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

This is how I do it.  JQuery is the holy grail of web design.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly with CSS (there are border hacks to create shapes that look like triangles, etc but I don't recommend them).

Instead an approach used now, by google, twitter, etc is to have an image that contains all the little icons, load that once, and offset the image using:

```
background-image: url("sprite-icons.png");
background-position: -176px -96px;
height: 14px;
width: 14px;
```